# Is lower bound in Java exclusive or inclusive?

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am reading Java the Complete Reference 7th edition, and it says that lower bound in Java Generics are exclusive, but I found the opposite [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) (It says that it is inclusive.) Is it because SE 6 differs from SE 7?

Edit: Java the Complete Reference 7th edition discussed **SE 6**.

Comment: Where exactly does it say that generic bounds in java 7 are exclusive?

Comment: @Bohemian You mean the book? It is mentioned in 'Using Wildcard Arguments' in Generics chapter. This edition discusses SE 6, not 7, so I thought there might be a difference.

Comment: Well the book is wrong! Generic bounds are *inclusive* no matter which version of java you are using. Just because some bozo writes something in a book does not make it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the specification, they use the word "subtype" in parametrization to mean inclusive subtype.  In section 4.10, it defines the phrase "proper subtype/proper supertype" to mean exclusive subtype/supertype while "subtype/supertype" means inclusive subtype/supertype.

Answer (score 2):

The bound is inclusive.

It is very easy to [try it](http://ideone.com/WwI9ZC) by yourself:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
                addNumbers(new ArrayList<Integer>());   
        }
        public static void addNumbers(List<? super Integer> list) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        list.add(i);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't really answered the question. I don't have a compiler handy, so I can't tell if your code compiles. Is the bound inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: @CameronSkinner It's inclusive. The link he provided will compile and run for you, online.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the short version. Thanks @WChargin for clarifying :)